# Как приостановить выполнение кода при выполнении DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

У меня есть DialogFragment и фрагмент из которого он запускается. Во фрагмент есть метод, который должен выполнятся при нажатии на определенную кнопку в диалоге. AlertDialog мне не подходит так как я хочу сделать свою разметку, setView в нем тоже, хочу закруглить углы. Я так понимаю DialogFragment выполняется не в UI потоке и поэтому код продолжает выполняться. Пытался выполнить метод внутри DialogFragment, но мне как-то нужно обновить recyclerview после нажатия на кнопку в диалоге.
Может это как то можно реализовать через интерфейс или хэндлер? Или как правильно задержать выполнение кода?

Код диалога:

```
    @NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    builder = new Dialog(getContext());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.ask);
    builder.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    builder.getWindow().setLayout(420, 230);
    activity = ((MainActivity2) getActivity());
    Button btnReopenId = builder.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button btnCancelId = builder.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    ImageView image = builder.findViewById(R.id.im);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_warning_24);
    btnReopenId.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCancelId.setOnClickListener(this);
    return builder;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button4:
                SQLiteOpenHelper exe = new ExeDatabase(getContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db = exe.getWritableDatabase();
                db.delete("EXE", "NAME=?", new String[]{bs});
                db.close();
                builder.dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                builder.dismiss();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Код фрагмента:

```
  public void onClick5(int position, String bs, View v) {
            if(download[position]==null){
                CustomDialogFragment dialog = new CustomDialogFragment(2, bs);
                dialog.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "custom");
            }
                findall(positio);
                adapter.changeDatass(nameArray, imageArray, download, favorite, position); // Два метода что должны выполнится после.
```

Comment: Не до конца понятно что у вас за задача. Вы хотите 2 строки из конца вопроса выполнить по нажатию на кнопку в диалоге, который перед этими строками показываете? Если да, то эти строки надо из диалога вызывать, когда в нём будет кнопка нажата, а не после команды на отображение диалога.

Comment: Просто метод задействует много переменных фрагмента, и он изменяет существующий массив в фрагменте и мне как то нужно вызвать метод обновления recycler'a и передать в него массив, но я не понимаю как это реализовать в диалоге.

Comment: Всю эту беду выполняй в отдельной функции, а вызывай её из диалога

Comment: @DrMcSheen а как получить ссылку на текущий фрагмент в диалоге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вырвал из проекта, смотри. Диалог создаётся прям в теле фрагмента, ничего никуда передавать не надо.

```
        /*-------Dialog_Edit_2_Buttons-----*/
    final EditText edText;
    String sBtn1 = "Ок";
    String sBtn2 = "Отмена";
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    final View v1 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dialog_edit, null);
    dialog.setView(v1);
    final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
    TextView tv1 = v1.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setText(c6.getText().toString());
    edText = v1.findViewById(R.id.edText);
    edText.setText(textb);
    edText.setSelection(edText.getText().length()); // курсор в конец текста
    Button btn1 = v1.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setText(sBtn1);
    Button btn2 = v1.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setText(sBtn2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            // кнопка 1 ----------
            try {
                E6 = Double.valueOf(edText.getText().toString().replace(" ", ""));
                alert.dismiss();
                if (!bDemo)
                    update_MyOrdersTable();
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                toast.setText("Введите число");
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });//----------
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            // кнопка 2 ---------
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });//--------
    alert.show();
```

**dialog_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:padding="3dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/qudrat"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="center|clip_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lL1edText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/qudrat"
        android:gravity="center|clip_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|clip_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                    android:text="Oк"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                    android:text="Отмена"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное) Я почему то сам не допер что можно и так) Еще раз спасибо)